# Как декодировать JSON ответ содержащий кирилицу

Tags: c++, json, парсер, idhttp

Помогите пожалуйста, пишу парсер сообщений для сайта, работа идет через JSON.
Платформа C++ Builder XE8.

```
UnicodeString answer=IdHTTP1->Get(Url);
```

Ответ получаю в виде:

```
{"data": [{"\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e-     \u0424\u0440\u0430\u043d\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f",     "\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434": "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0440-    \u043d", "\u0417\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435": "288.00"}, 
        ....]
"structure": ["\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c",     "\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", "\u0417\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435"]}
```

Как перевести символы `\u####` в кирилицу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам не нужно переводить строки в кириллицу, вам нужно распарсить объект JSON. На выходе вы получите объект с декодированными юникодовыми строками.

В Delphi / С++ Builder для этого есть [TJSONObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject). См. [How to parse this JSON in C++ Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24531767)